# Converting a javascript string into an existing javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with this problem. I have a function to accept the path and also the same time I have a variable that I want to condition with.

Here is my problem: I want to make a string type that will act as an access to my variable.
In my situation, I have a `roles.operation` variable which I want to access it dynamically.

The roles variable has an array with the values of:

```
roles.operations = ['document','article','document-type'];
```

with this variable I want this to be access dynamically.

Here is what I've tried, which in replacePath i have the value of document-type:

```
export const createVariable = (roles,path) => {
     const replacePath = path.replace(/-/g,"_"); 
     const finalPath = window[`roles.operations.${replacePath}`];
     console.log(finalPath);
}
```

this gives me undefined.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Could you please show some examples of expected results

Comment: As has been requested by half a dozen people now: please provide the required details to avoid users having to guess what specific problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
const finalPath = window['roles']['operations'][replacePath];
```

or

```
const finalPath = window.roles.operations[replacePath];
```

Comment: the first method:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'operations' of undefined

the second 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'operations' of undefined

Comment: @DarkVader191919 You have to maintain same variable name. Note the 'operation' in your variable vs the 'operations' in the finalPath

Comment: @K K I don't get it sorry ?

Comment: @DarkVader191919 Rename roles.operation to roles.operations and prefer window.roles.operations

Comment: sorry thats actually operations. not operation. but still cant access it

Comment: i also tried this one but doesn't console.log(window['roles']['operations']);

Comment: const finalPath = window.roles.operations[replacePath];
  console.log(finalPath);